# SQL: Updating each value of 4 rows at a time

Tags: sql

Hi so currently I have a table that looks like this:
[image]

What I would like to have is an sql query that will update the columns: hplayer,aplayer,g1h,g1a,g2h,g2a,g3h,g3a,g4h,g4a 

For each row that has the matchid set to "3" for example. 

**Is this possible? How would I do it?**

Comment: Sounds like a simple UPDATE statement.

Comment: This has been asked/answered many times, including the most basic of sql tutorials. Have you tried google?

Answer (score 0):

Update Syntax:

```
UPDATE table-name 
SET column-name = value, column-name = value, ...
WHERE condition
```

Try something like this: (Alter the ? to the values you want)

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET player = ?,
    aplayer = ?,
    g1h = ?, 
    g1a = ?,
    g2h = ?,
    g2a = ?,
    g3h = ?,
    g3a = ?,
    g4h = ?,
    g4a = ?
WHERE matchid = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table_name 
set hplayer=1,
    aplayer=1,
    g1=1,
    g1a=1,
    g2h=1,
    g2a=1,
    g3h=1,
    g3a=1,
    g4h=1,
    g4a=1 
where matchid=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Example from [w3schools SQL Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

In your case:

```
UPDATE table_name
  SET hplayer="11",
  aplayer="22",
  g1h="33",
  g1a="44",
  g2h="55",
  g2a="66",
  g3h="77",
  g3a="88",
  g4h="99",
  g4a="00" 
  WHERE matchid = "3";
```

Also try [searching](https://www.google.gr/search?q=sql%20update) `sql update`.

Comment: This isnt an anwer. This should be a comment,